# My "alret()" function is not working in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-8

I'm a beginner at vue and trying to execute alert function on click of the button but the error that I am getting is `Uncaught ReferenceError: addTask is not defined`

**Here are my codes:-**

```
<template>
    
    <div class="col-md-8 mt-4">
        <div class="card card-default">
            <div class="card-header">
                Task Form
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="./api/task" method="POST" onClick="addTask">
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Task title" class="form-control">

                        
                    </div>
                    <input type="submt" value="Add Task" class="btn btn-info">
                </form>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
</template>

<script >
    
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('component mounted.')
        },

        methods: {
            addTask(){
                alert('Adding The Task');
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Can anyone tell me the solution and explain the reason.

Comment: `onClick="addTask"` for this to work, addTask would need to be a global method ... `v-on:click="addTask"` may do what you want - to be honest, your code looks like you aren't using any vuejs at all in the markup - so, why bother with vuejs

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html. Also, you want `type="submit"`, not `type="submt"`

Comment: @JaromandaX can you answer the question so that I can close it.

Comment: why would you close it? just mark the answer (once I post it) as accepted

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes That's what I meant by "Closing the question".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onClick="addTask" for this to work, `addTask` would need to be a global method

instead, use the vuejs

```
v-on:click="addTask"
```

or

```
@click="addTask"
```